# Where can I find Apex code that would affect the body of an article?

Tags: apex, articles

This is a long shot, mostly because I don't know anything about Apex; please bear with me.

I am inspecting someone else's system and they have a custom coded solution which involves putting an article link in the footer of each Article Body they send out. Does anyone have the slightest clue/could anyone point me in the direction of where I can look in the code for this custom implementation? I'm literally at this stage going through Apex classes and such and looking at last modified, but I don't see anything recent.

This screenshot is pretty much all I have to go off of. This link only shows up in the email, not in the article. I don't see a custom field under ArticleTypes > Article, or anywhere else for that matter, whatever changes he made do *not* show up in the View Setup Trail audit log, and I'm just not sure how that link is getting added in there.

[image]

Comment: Can you check if there is a formula field returning URL? Can you post a picture

Comment: @SantanuBoral added screenshot + information

Comment: Is this email template?

Comment: @SantanuBoral no

Comment: what is this screenshot?

Comment: This is likely achieved with an email template that is selected when the Agent chooses to share Knowledge Articles via public URL. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_widget_setup.htm

Comment: @MarkPond Yes! The Email template was buried. Also SantanuBoral, you were correct! Thanks!